# CSS: How to break images into rows?

Tags: css

I want to create a photo album with rows of images.  Currently all my images are appearing in one row.  Say if I upload 15 images, what is the CSS code to break them into 3 rows .. 5 images on each row?  Sorry this probably is really easy but I am a beginner in CSS.  This is the code I am currently using.

EDIT:  Here is another part of the code I am not sure if it is a container.

```
.flickr-photoset-img{ 
float: left; 
}

.flickr-photoset-box {
  padding: 10px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width: 130px;
  height: 130px;
}
```

Comment: what's the width of each images? what's the with of your page?

Comment: I doubt you can do this by using only CSS. If pages are dynamic you need some kind of scripting to create right markup, or if the image sizes are the same you could make your containers wide enough to only accommodate 5 images in a row and leave them floating.

Comment: `img`s are `display: inline` by default, so you'll need to do `display: block` as well as `float: left`, and every fifth `img`, add another class (`.imgBreak` maybe) and set it to: `.imgBreak {clear: left;}`.

Comment: For example: http://jsfiddle.net/JLz3z/

Comment: @Clement Ckh your question is quite vague, there are number of possible scenarios that you are describing, for precise answer you should at least provide information such as image sizes, are image aspect ratios the same, type of layout you are using (fixed or dynamic) or even your current HTML.

Comment: @JaredFarrish If you add a float to an element other than none it has a limited amount of display arguments, which it is mutated into automagically. Look at this spec http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#dis-pos-flo So a element that has `display:inline` and `float:(left|right)` has `display:block`automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way would be to restrict the container size.

```
.container {
   width: 500px; /* look i'm now showing 5 images per line */
}
.img {
  /* height: 100px; width: 100px; */
  float: left;
}

<div class="container">
  ...
  <img ...>
  <img ...>
  <img ...>
  <img ...>
  <img ...>
  <img ...> <!-- I will wrap to a new line -->
  ...
</div>
```

[Example here](http://jsfiddle.net/VpqxJ/1/)

After reading *briefly* about Flicker and Drupal - I think the css class you want to edit is `flickr-photoset`

```
.flickr-photoset {
   width: 500px; /* really you can set this to whatever */
}
```

Comment: That's assuming you have image of the same size and fixed layout.

Comment: I don't know, I think my `clear: left` class is pretty simple, and no extra markup.

Comment: @rebus, yes that is an assumption - however for a 'photo' gallery with multiple images shown in rows i took the *safe assumption* that these were thumbnails - which would likely be the same size (in the case of an landscape vs portrait modifications would be required)

Comment: @JaredFarrish No extra markup boss - again I have provided an example with a container visible so the OP can see what i've done - I bet his images are in a container as well. I'm not saying yours is wrong. I like your solution as well. Mine is just a different approach to solve the problem. The OP was vague enough that a number of different solutions can achieve the desired output.

Comment: @rlemon agreed, for the images of same size container width is the way to go in my opinion (also fewer classes then Jareds suggestion).

Comment: Yes all my images are thumbnails of the same size.  Thank you guys I will slowly work it out.  I am not exactly sure how to use the DIV tag.  I am using Drupal 7 and my images are generated by flickr module.  I am trying to change how it displays images in the css file.

Comment: @Clement Ckh then just set width of image container (a div presumably) to `image width * 5` as rlemon and Ionut are suggesting. Also you can navigate HTML of your page using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox or developer tools for Chrome opened with `Ctrl - Shift - i`

Comment: @rebus Please have a look at the edited code.  That is the full code and I am not sure if box = container?

Comment: @rlemon Awesome that worked!  And thanks to all of you who helped :)

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should probably have a [div](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) wrapping your images.

The important thing to know is that your images will automatically skip to the next row if the sum of your images widths exceeds the with of their wrapping div.

For example if you have a **600px** wide wrapping div and four images each measuring **250px** in width they will be listed **in two rows**.

[Here](http://brandnewbox.co.uk/articles/details/using_css_to_produce_an_image_gallery/) you can find a tutorial which explains exactly what you need to do for your gallery.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with placing `<br />` tag after fifth image. With CSS you can add style like this

```
CSS

.images{
float:left
}

.clear{
clear:both
}


HTML

<img class=images ... />
<img class=images ... />
<img class=images ... />
<img class=images ... />
<img class=images ... />
<img class=clear ... />
<img class=images ... />
<img class=images ... />
<img class=images ... />
<img class=images ... />
<img class=clear ... />
<img class=images ... />
<img class=images ... />
<img class=images ... />
<img class=images ... />
```

Comment: `<br />` does not fit into HTML's purpose of separating form from presentation - unless you're applying a CSS rule directly to it such as `clear: both`. (In which case, you're probably applying it to the wrong element.)

Comment: The rules are only there to make life easier, not harder.  Sometimes you have to break the rules.